# Find user and insert products in that user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wand to create document inside the user by using his object ID.

This is my schema

```
const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
product_name: {
    type: String,
},
product_price: {
    type: Number,
},
});

const sellersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
user_firstname: {
    type: String
},
user_lastname: {
    type: String
},
user_mobile: {
    type: Number
},
products: [productsSchema]
});
```

And this is my code

```
module.exports.uploadProducts = function(productDetails, callback) {
    var id = productDetails.userId;
    db.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": ObjectId(id) }, { $set: { products: 
      productDetails } }, { new: true }, callback)
 }
```

But in this case products are updating in the particular user but I want to insert document inside that user based on ID.

Comment: Could you explain it in detail ***But in this case products are updating in the particular user but I want to insert document inside that user based on ID.***?

Comment: Actually I want to insert products inside the user document like nested document as I mention in my schema.

Comment: Use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator to update an array in mongodb

Comment: It's working for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/):

```
module.exports.uploadProducts = function(productDetails, callback) {
    var id = productDetails.userId;
    db.update({ "_id": ObjectId(id) }, { $push: { products: 
      productDetails } }, callback)
 }
```

Hope this helps you.